# If a beginner paraglider / paramotor wing fully stalls, how much vertical distance is needed for recovery?

Tags: stall, paraglider

In paramotoring, a beginner wing is a wing with A, B, C, D and F (brake) lines.

When a full stall is induced, a pilot may fall a long, long ways before the wing will recover, and most will need to plan for it.

On a calm day, what is the vertical recovery distance for a beginner wing?

As an example, one could use the [Gin Bolero 6](https://www.gingliders.com/en/paragliders/bolero-6/)

Comment: It's difficult to find numbers like that.  It's going to depend on how deeply you get into the stall.  If you push it until the wing is folding back on itself, you are going to lose 50ft minimum even on an EN-A wing.  If you get off the brakes as soon as the wing starts to fold, you may only lose 10-20 ft.

Comment: "a beginner wing is a wing with A, B, C, D and F (brake) lines" this isn't necessarily true..  a beginner wing is one with good handling characteristics for beginners regardless of construction.

Comment: @JeffUK is there a wing you had in mind when you say this?

Comment: @tuskiomi Independence Cruiser3 is EN-A rated (beginner) and only has 3 risers + brakes

Comment: Do paragliders use the same wings as paramotors?  If so the title could say "paraglider/paramotor" instead of "paramotor" (my recent edit)

Comment: I read in the link that "The Bolero 6 is intended as a first paraglider, " so I assume the answer to previous comment is "yes" and will further edit accordingly; feel free to roll back if this is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any extra second in recovery adds up to 60 meters of height. For this reason there is no way to tell how much height the next stall will require.

From the manual of Gin Bolero 6:

Page28, Dynamic Stall: the sink rate in a controlled stall induced by pilot is approx 8m/s.

Page20, Spiral Dive: you need 120-150m clearance to attempt a spiral Dive.

If you took an SIV course and trained in Dynamic Stall, you will find the answer. This is as far as I can go at answering your question. Any further appreciation or direct answering would be a mistake and huge liability.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I guess I'm misunderstanding what you mean when you say a) 1 second of recovery is up to 60m, and b) the sink rate in a controlled stall is 8m/s. That's a huge difference, can you give some more details on what it means?

Comment: The terminal velocity in free fall is roughly 60m/s. So at terminal speed every second is worth up to roughly 60m of height. As for the figure of 8m/s, that is quoted from the manual of the paraglider suggested in the question. It says there that a stall induced by the pilot leads to a sink rate of 8m/s.

Comment: The stall is not something the wing would recover without active piloting. Please check the dynamic stall portion in the manual of the wing you have specified. If the pilot doesn’t control the wing, the stall becomes irrecoverable. For this reason is not like if the pilot induced the stall then released the brakes the wing would recover within that height and time. All the pilots presenting collapse testings are doing those well within the self-recovery envelope of the wing and in ideal flight conditions. The stall and collapse accidents happen outside the wing self-recovery.